# Spring can't find properties

Tags: spring

I have this definition in my application context:

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  ...
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:propfile.properties"/>
```

My propfile.properties:

```
parallelism=4
```

And as it is part of a maven project I located this file like this:

```
-src/main/java
-src/main/resources
--propfile.properties
```

Now, in my component:

```
@WebService
@Component
public class MyService{
      @Value("#{parallelism}")
      private Integer parallelism;

      ....

}
```

In initialization phase it gives me

> Field or property 'parallelism' cannot be found on object of type
>   'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext

Why? Moreover is it correct to use the property-placeholder in a web application environment?Or is there any other way to set properties?

Comment: Is your property-placeholder in the same spring configuration file as your component-scan? Is it in a different spring configuration file, are you importing it?

Comment: Also the # prefix referrs to spring expression language queries, if you're referencing a property file you should use the $ prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your configuration file as below:

```
<bean id="propfile" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath*:propfile.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

And Component as:

```
@WebService
@Component
public class MyService{
      @Value("${parallelism}")
      private Integer parallelism;

      ....

}
```

Moreover, you can also use as below, to access the complete property file:

```
     @Component
        public class MyService{
              @Resource(name="propfile")
              private Properties propfile;

              ....

   }
```